# MAJOR Y Axis problem [R studio] (is it adding up my variables?)

Tags: r, ggplot2

[NEW GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTmj0.jpg) I'm very new to R Studio and thought I had a hang on making graphs using ggplot2 for my final project in class, but I have run into an issue I can't seem to solve. I'm using a dataframe that I subsetted and it looks like this with 5 other countries added to it.

```
Location    date        new_cases 
1.  China   2020-03-14  32
2   China   2020-03-15  26
3   China   2020-03-16  30
4   China   2020-03-17  25
5   China   2020-03-18  44
6   China   2020-03-19  54
7   China   2020-03-20  94
8   China   2020-03-21  55
9   China   2020-03-22  130
10  China   2020-03-23  63
11  China   2020-03-24  93
12  China   2020-03-25  70
13  China   2020-03-26  121
14  China   2020-03-27  115
15  China   2020-03-28  102
16  China   2020-03-29  123
17  China   2020-03-30  76
18  China   2020-03-31  81
19  China   2020-04-01  82
20  China   2020-04-02  71
21  China   2020-04-03  79
22  China   2020-04-04  32
23  China   2020-04-05  59
24  China   2020-04-06  63
25  China   2020-04-07  53
26  China   2020-04-08  91
```

I successfully graphed something earlier using a different variable, but this time for some reason even though the "new_cases" category ranges does not surpass ~15,000 in my graph it's going up to 2 million. I even tested graphing just one country instead of all five and the y-axis scale worked perfectly, so I'm not sure if it's adding up my variables or something? Here's the code I used to combine the subsetted data into one frame as well as the code I used for the graph.

```
new_cases_allcountries <- rbind(China_Covid_newcases, Italy_Covid_newcases, France_Covid_newcases, Singapore_Covid_newcases, Sweden_Covid_newcases)
View(new_cases_allcountries)

##change date format 
as.date=function(x, origin='2020-01-21') as.Date(x, origin=origin)
new_cases_allcountries$date <- as.Date(new_cases_allcountries$date,
                     format = "%m-%d-%y")
##filter dates from March 2020 to December 2020  
new_cases <- new_cases_allcountries %>%
  filter(date >= as.Date('2020-03-14') & date <= as.Date('2020-12-01'))
min(new_cases$date)
max(new_cases$date)
View(new_cases)

##plot 

New_Cases_Graph <- ggplot(new_cases, aes(date, new_cases, colour = location)) +
  geom_line()
New_Cases_Graph
```

here's the graph I made and it has that very weird y-axis

[image: here's the graph I made and it has that very weird y-axis]

Comment: the graph you posted only goes up to 100k not 2mil

Comment: Check the output of `sort(new_cases[, 'new_cases'])` and `sort(new_cases[, 'new_cases'], descending = T)` . If you have values over 100,000 and close to -50000 then the graph is working fine. I highly suspect it as a data issue, not a ggplot issue. Also, as @rawr points out, your graph does not go to 2 million, so not sure where you're getting that number

Comment: Alternatively, please edit your question to include the output of `dput(new_cases)` so we can see your data ourselves

Comment: Voting to close. The problem is clearly in the France data which has not been supplied.

Comment: My bad! I had made a graph earlier that went up to 2mil and I guess it changed when I ran it again differently and I didn't even notice. To get rid of the negative values (because this data is about new COVID cases every day) I went ahead and used the "new_data_smoothed" variable from my original dataset (it's from OWID: https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/tree/master/public/data). I posted the revised graph in my original post. How would you recommend I clean it up? It looks very messy to me with the y axis, but maybe it isn't as bad as I thought.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, like I said I'm pretty new to this so I had no idea if this was completely off!